# How to 'split' a pandas df column based on conditional and pivot the df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a df of 4400 rows. Created this df on reading xlsx file.

To make my question clear I created an example df.

This gives the following result (a simplefied version of my true problem):

```
shop          amount
0   shop A      15
1   product 1   4
2   product 2   5
3   product 3   6
4   BBBB        19
5   product 1   7
6   product 2   9
7   product 3   3
8   CCCC        21
9   product 1   6
10  product 2   7
11  product 3   8
12  DDDD        18
13  product 1   4
14  product 2   3
15  product 3   11
```

As you can see, behind every shopname is the total number of three products sold in that shop.
Every shop has the same products. But every shop has a total different name.

Having 4400 rows and many shops with all different names (but exactly the same products) I would like to pivot my df: shopnames as first column and all the products as columns names. And logically, the amount of products per shop correctly in the right column.

There is (for me that is) no way of distinghuishing between shop name en product name. However: the list of products beneath each shopname is exactly the same and in same order.

I my self have no idea how to 'filter'all the shop names from the productnames.
Hopefully one of you has an idea for me.
Many thanks again! greetings Jan

ps: I used this code for making example df:

```
d = {'shop': ['shop A', 'product 1', 'product2','product 3','BBBB', 'product 1', 'product 2','product 3','CCCC', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3','DDDD', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3'], 'amount': [15,4,5,6,19,7,9,3,21,6,7,8, 18,4,3,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df
```

Comment: If you're going to edit your input data after the question has been answered, you ought to call it out in the question so the correct answer doesn't magically become wrong.

Comment: do you know the number of elements in shops beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your data set, `product2` should be `product 2`.  After fixing that you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'shop': ['shop A', 'product 1', 'product 2','product 3','shop B', 'product 1', 'product 2','product 3','shop C', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3','shop D', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3'], 'amount': [15,4,5,6,19,7,9,3,21,6,7,8, 18,4,3,1]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Create grouping column
df['g']  = np.where(df['shop'].str.contains('shop'), df['shop'], np.nan)
df = df.ffill()

# Get rows that have totals by shop
total_rows = df.groupby('g')['amount'].idxmax().values

# Drop total rows
df = df.loc[~df.index.isin(total_rows)]

# Rename columns
df.columns = ['product','amount','shop']

# Pivot
df.pivot_table(index='shop',columns='product',values='amount')
```

Output

```
product product 1   product 2   product 3
shop            
shop A          4           5           6
shop B          7           9           3
shop C          6           7           8
shop D          4           3           1
```

Comment: Chris thanks! being a 58 year old student I'm impressed! But... I have to admit I made a too simple example. Sorry. My example gives the impression the word shop is in every name, but this is not the case..... Hopefully you can come up with an other idea. Is there something possible with the products being the same for every shop? thanks again!! ps: I changed the example in my post.

Comment: @Janneman is there always the same number of products?  or perhaps the product names always contain 'product'?

Comment: Chris, the number of products are not the same. Only the product names are the same. thanks again!

Comment: Chris, it works fine on the example. What happens when applying this to my real df: it pivots, it creates the colummns, is gets all the different shops in the first column / index. But.... in my original df there are no NaN values. Alltough your code works with my example df, it creates a lot ( allmost all) NaN values in the pivot df.

Comment: You should accept this answer as it suits the sample data provided, and ask another one with enhanced requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shop names are unique, and the products are repeated:

```
d = {'shop': ['shop A', 'product 1', 'product 2','product 3','BBBB', 'product 1', 'product 2','product 3','CCCC', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3','DDDD', 'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3'], 'amount': [15,4,5,6,19,7,9,3,21,6,7,8, 18,4,3,1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

g = df.groupby('shop').size().reset_index()
df['g'] = np.where(df['shop'].isin(g[g[0]==1]['shop'].values), df['shop'], np.nan)
# # Create grouping column
# df['g']  = np.where(df['shop'].str.contains('shop'), df['shop'], np.nan)
df = df.ffill()

# Get rows that have totals by shop
total_rows = df.groupby('g')['amount'].idxmax().values

# Drop total rows
df = df.loc[~df.index.isin(total_rows)]

# Rename columns
df.columns = ['product','amount','shop']

# Pivot
df.pivot_table(index='shop',columns='product',values='amount')
```

Comment: Chris thanks again. I'll come back to you within a few hours. Later! greetings Jan

Comment: @Janneman Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it solves the issue.